# Scala Lift - Return model as json object

Tags: json, scala, lift

I have the following:

```
object API_Chat extends RestHelper {

    serve {

        var response = Chat.findAll(

            ("room" -> "aroom")
            ~
            ("handle" -> "ahandle")

        ).map(_.asJValue)

        JsonResponse(write(response(0)) :: Nil)

    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is return a json object that contains all of the values from the model Chat.

When I get the response however it looks like this:

```
["{\"name\":\"J1M\",\"_id\":\"4f8d55b240d41dcad5c3f982\",\"target\":\"all\",\"time\":1334662578,\"room\":\"jroom\",\"value\":\":)\",\"user\":\"j1m\",\"handle\":\"f1aaa95db5150a6330552e30918728b5\",\"level\":\"_1\"}"]
```

Obviously I'm trying to return only one item so unsure why its wrapped in an array, also it seems to have escaped the json string.

Can anyone shine some light on how to make this work?

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were trying to send as your JsonResponse, but your response val is a List[JValue].  Calling write(response(0)) will serialize the first JValue in the List to a String.  You are then concatenating that String with Nil to make a List[String] that contains a single element.  The single parameter version of JsonResponse.apply takes a JValue, so an implicit conversion in net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL (seq2jvalue) that converts a Seq[A] into a JArray is getting invoked.....  and that's why you are seeing a JSON array as the response.

If you just want to return the first element, you should be able to use:

```
JsonResponse(response(0))
```